# How to add minus sign before SASS variable?

Tags: loops, variables, sass

Hello i was try to add minus sign(-) before {$i}px variable but this is not working i want before minus sign(-) like .top-minus-1 { top: -1px;} any solution i want out of css is like .top-minus-0 { top: -0px;} to .top-minus-10 { top: -10px;}. Thanks in advance

```css
@for $i from 0 through 10 {
    .top-minus-#{$i} {
        top: -#{$i}px;
    }
}
```

Comment: You code works fine for me on https://www.sassmeister.com Are you using a really old version of Sass?

Comment: Yes my SASS version is old. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to add the minus in front, you could multiply `i` with `-1`:

```
@for $i from 0 through 10 {
    .top-minus-#{$i} {
        top: #{$i*-1}px;
    }
}
```

Note that running your snippet on [sassmeister](https://www.sassmeister.com/) gives me the desired output.

Comment: Thanks Stephane Vanraes

Comment: You could also do `top: $i * -1px;` without the `#{}`, might be easier for folks to read.